# Cannot send POST request with jQuery and AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I am trying to send POST data to my php file notify.php. For that I am using:

```
$.post("notify.php", { phone : phone_number });
```

phone_number is the input name in HTML. But the POST isn't getting sent. I used Firebug firefox plugin to check AJAX error and got:

```
TypeError: 'stepUp' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLInputElement.
...i+"["+k+"]",n)}):f(i,o)}function f(i,o){o=c.isFunction(o)?o():o;e[e.length]=enco...
```

What is wrong?

Comment: `{ "phone" : $('#phone_number').value() }`

Comment: I don't think that error is related to `$.post()`.

Comment: @Anthony I think you mean `.val()`. But he could have done `phone_number = $('#phone_number').val()`.

Comment: @Barmar but if i remove $.post thing i dont get errors.

Comment: Do you use something like `$.ajaxSetup()` or `$.ajaxSuccess()` to define a default handler for all AJAX requests? I don't think there's anything called `stepUp` in jQuery itself.

Comment: @Barmar it worked. pls make it an answer so i can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the variable before using it, else it will give error in console and send an undefined value to the AJAX server.

```
var phone_number = $('#phone_number').val();
```

This assumes the input is defined like:

```
<input type="text" id="phone_number">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the variable like this first: phone_number = $('input[name=phone_number]').val()

Comment: I think you mean `$('input[name=phone_number]').val()`